# "Еще одно качество — это смелость". Где ставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

"Еще одно качество — это смелость".
Где тут ставить тире? Или оно вообще тут не нужно, а нужно двоеточие после слова "качество"?

Answer (score 3):

**Еще одно (необходимое) качество — это смелость.**

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при наличии связки ЭТО. Двоеточие в таких случаях не применяется.

Answer (score 1):

Надо ставить тире.
Тире ставится перед *это, это есть, это значит, вот*, если сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже или неопределенной формой, присоединяется посредством этих слов к подлежащему, например:

«Коммунизм — это есть Советская власть плюс электрификация всей страны.»
В.И. Ленин.

«Поэзия — это огненный взор юноши, кипящего избытком сил» и «Романтизм» — вот первое слово, огласившее пушкинский период; народность – вот альфа и омега нового периода.» В.Г. Белинский.